# Is the sequence of functions uniformly convergent? Analyse the pointwise convergence.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, functions

$n^2$$\frac{(1-cos(x/n))}{x}$

I don't know how to analyse the limit when n tends to infinity. Do you need to use Taylor series for that one?

Comment: Well, let's think about it pointwise first - we know that $n^{2} \to \infty$, and $x/n \to 0$, so $\cos(x/n) \to 1$, so $1-\cos(x/n) \to 0$. So what happens to the limit will depend on how fast $1-\cos(x/n) \to 0$; certainly a Taylor approximation will help!

Comment: I'm trying to use Taylor approximation on cos(x/n), but it's not very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $ f_n(x) = \displaystyle n^2\frac{1 - \cos(x/n)}{x} $

You have $ 1 - \cos(x/n) = \displaystyle \frac{x^2}{2n^2} - \frac{x^4}{24n^4} + o(x^4/n^4) $

So, by plugging in, you get that $ \displaystyle f_n(x) = \frac{x}{2} + o(x^2/n)$, and you get the pointwise convergence to $ x/2 $.

Now, notice that the limit function is unbounded near $ +\infty $, so you'll need to study the uniform convergence on compact subsets (closed intervals) of $ \mathbb{R} $, otherwise the $\infty$-norm won't exist.

On $ [a, b] $, we have that $ \displaystyle \|f_n - f \|_\infty = \|-\frac{x^3}{24n^2} + o(\frac{x^3}{n^2})\|_\infty \leq \frac{b^3}{24n^2} + o(\frac{1}{n^2}) \rightarrow 0 $, thus giving the uniform convergence, on compact subsets (which is enough for all limit switching theorems).